# Flink Reading a S3 file causing Jackson dependency issue

Tags: java, aws-sdk, apache-flink

I a reading a config YAML file in my link application. I want to keep this config file on S3 filesystem but when using aws-sdk in my pom and trying to read I am getting this error. I know this is due to Jackson's conflict dependency but I am not able to resolve it. Please help me to get it to resolve.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.enable([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser$Feature;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader.(PartitionsLoader.java:54)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionMetadataFactory.create(RegionMetadataFactory.java:30)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.initialize(RegionUtils.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionMetadata(RegionUtils.java:53)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegion(RegionUtils.java:107)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createSigner(AmazonS3Client.java:4016)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4913)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4872)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1472)
    at com.bounce.processor.EventProcessor.main(EventProcessor.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:576)

This this code that I am using to read the file

```
        AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

        S3Object object = amazonS3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(S3_PROD_BUCKET, para.get("topology")));
        InputStream awsinputStream = object.getObjectContent();
```

This is my pom.xml

```
        <!-- Flink dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-filesystem_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.format.parquet.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-parquet_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans/yamlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>yamlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.uber/h3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uber</groupId>
            <artifactId>h3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.davidmoten</groupId>
            <artifactId>geo</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-elasticsearch6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch7_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.allegro.schema.json2avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch7_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.756</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Which Flink version are you using?
Starting from Flink 1.4, Flink is shading Jackson away, to avoid such conflicts: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7418

Comment: I am using flink 1.9.1

Comment: @RobertMetzger I do not think my project jar has issue. its taking Jackson jar from Flink lib dir /usr/lib/flink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.9.1.jar

Comment: There are no `com.fasterxml.jackson.*` classes in `flink-dist_2.11-1.9.1.jar`: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rmetzger/db1513544f0edf95a533d02dc7ef0895/raw/f3720be8cbf459b734ab14c1761cc791c4f12b5b/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @RobertMetzger then why i get this printed when i tried in my codecode System.out.println(ObjectMapper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()); and it print the output : /usr/lib/flink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.9.1.jar. and how can i resolve it. please suggest

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println( com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource());` ? I guess you were importing Flink's shaded object mapper.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the answer about conflict solely from POM is highly unlikely. Instead, You should refer to the maven dependency plugin, by invoking the following command:

`mvn dependency:tree`

This will print all the dependencies and the dependencies of those dependencies, this way You will be able to locate which of libraries You are importing has the transitive dependency on Jackson and You will be able to mark it as excluded.

Note: What You are really looking for in this dependency tree are the Jackson dependencies with different versions, so You don't need to exclude them all.

Comment: I tried this in my code         System.out.println(ObjectMapper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource());
and it print the output :     /usr/lib/flink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.9.1.jar

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't mean that there is no clash. You should really go with dependency tree.

Comment: I already tried by mvn dependency tree and tried to exclude all Jackson dependency, still not able to resolve it.  Please provide the solution for this.